# Bundle dependency resolution

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse

I have built two JBossFuse projects which are deployed as bundles in osgi container.
Let the bundles be A and B.Bundle A is dependent on a dependency called pdfbox which is of version 1.8.13,where as Bundle B is dependent on the same dependency which is of version 2.0.8.Both versions of pdfbox dependency have already been deployed as bundles.How should be the pom files of bundle A and bundle B configured such that it uses only the respective versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look into the exported package versions. In the case of pdfbox the package versions seem to match the bundle versions.

So in this case you should be able to leverage the defaults of the maven-bundle-plugin for your bundle A and B. The generated imports should use a version of [1.8,2) for the 1.8.13 dependency and [2.0,3) for the 2.0.8 version. So this should make sure that each bundle only binds to the correct version of pdfbox.